# How to show header on first page of chapter=

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

an anyone tell me why my header doenst start on the first page of my chapters? How can I let my header start on all the pages of the document? (Excluding my frontpage)

Thanks in advance

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{90pt}
\begin{document}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\transparent{1} \includegraphics[width=16cm]{images/test.jpg}}
\chapter{some chapter}
text
\newpage
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're using one of the standard classes, the internal definition of  `\chapter` includes `thispagestyle{plain}`. Maybe try adding this to your preamble: `\usepackage{etoolbox} \apptocmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}` (not tested).

Comment: If you have the chapter title there with big letters, you don't Need a Header with the same Information. Leaving it empty has been done for many many years.

Comment: also in all standard classes the syntax is `\chapter{my stuff}` not `\begin{chapter}`

Comment: @Johannes_B: It seems the O.P. has some logo in the header. If there's nothing else,  it makes sense, in my opinion.

Comment: I have indeed a logo in my header. Thanks for the help guys. @DavidCarlisle youre right, my bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See "7 Redefining `plain` style" of `fancyhdr`'s [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf). Applied to the simplified example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{LOGO}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[C]{LOGO}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{some chapter}
text
\newpage
text
\end{document}
```

Of course, the page number should be inserted somewhere.